# Using LISTAGG function with join tablee

Tags: sql, oracle, join, listagg

I want to use LISTAGG() function to aggregate NAME column in my SQL query. I have to join 3 tables. Table PRI2PR is my join-table.

Table PROJ_INW

```
        ID
----------
        12
```

Table PROJEKT

```
ID     NAME
---  ---------------
61    Józef Dawidowski
```

Table PRI2PR

```
ID    ID_PRIN    ID_PROJ 
---------- ---------- ---
9         12         61
```

My query:

```
SELECT pi.ID,
LISTAGG(pr.NAME, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY pr.NAME) AS PRO
FROM PROJ_INW pi
INNER JOIN PRI2PR pp ON pi.ID = pp.ID_PRIN
INNER JOIN PROJEKT pr ON pp.ID_PROJ = pr.ID
GROUP BY pi.ID, pr.NAME
```

**Question: How to correct my SQL statement to use LISTAGG() function in my case?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is basically fine.  Remove `pr.name` from the `group by`:

```
SELECT pi.ID,
       LISTAGG(pr.NAME, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY pr.NAME) AS PRO
FROM PROJ_INW pi INNER JOIN
     PRI2PR pp
     ON pi.ID = pp.ID_PRIN INNER JOIN
     PROJEKT pr
     ON pp.ID_PROJ = pr.ID
GROUP BY pi.ID;
```